# Angular and VS Code disable automatic reload/refresh

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, refresh, reload

when I am running my Angular app in the CLI with "ng serve", on every tiny change in the code, my app gets reloaded / refreshed. How can I stop that behaviour?
I know I have seen the command `ng serve --live-reload false`, but apparently, I have to reload everything then in browser by hand.

Weirdly, on my other desktop PC, not my laptop, I can just reload everything by default in VSCode by pressing `CTRL+S`, otherwise, no changes or reloads are done during changing the code otherwise. I would like to have this behaviour by default on my laptop also... How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Turn of the `autoSave` feature. This feature automatically saves your files on any change which cause `ng serve` to reload the files.

#### To Change:

File > Preferences > Settings > Search `autoSave` > select `off`

#### User Settings after change:

```json
"files.autoSave": "off",
```

Comment: ok thanks, but I guess I had done it in another way: I had a start script, that executed the corresponding ng serve --live-reload false on every start. But the other solution is ok as well, the problem is just that if things crash, you don't have the actual status.

Comment: @MMM Could you please share the script?  where you keeps it under?  for every start

Answer (score 2):

No CLI command will solve the problem. This comes from your IDE which saves your file each time the code is modified. I think you can change that in the settings of it so that it only records at your request.

Answer (score 2):

I like the `Auto Save` feature, because of ... obvious reasons.

You have different settings:

> **off** - A dirty file is never automatically saved. 
>   **afterDelay** - A dirty file is automatically saved after ... 
>   **onFocusChange** - A dirty file is automatically saved when the editor loses focus. 
>   **onWindowChange** - A dirty file is automatically saved when the window loses focus.

My preference goes to **onFocusChange** 
You work in a file of choice without the auto reload and jumping cursors, when you are done the changes can be build

P.S: Why have I waited so long to search this annoying problem